# admob interstitial, viewpager and page rotation bug?

Tags: android, admob

I have a app that consists of a single Activity hosting a ViewPager.

That ViewPager has several fragments.

One of the fragments consists of a gridView.

When clicking on a gridItem, I launch an activity to display an Admob interstitial ad.

This works, but there seems to be a bug: if I rotate the device while the interstitial is being displayed, a second Interstitial activity is created and displayed ?

I tried changing from FragmentStatePagerAdapter to FragmentPagerAdapter, but that changes nothing.

Pseudo code:

1) in MainActivity:

```
Main Activity :: onCreate:
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()))

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter { ... }
```

2) in Fragment containing gridView:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

}

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AdmobInterstitial.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
};

@Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + requestCode + " - " + resultCode);
        // do other stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely occurs because you are launching your own Activity from which the Interstitial is shown. I suspect that what is occurring is that the Intent for your Activity is queued and partially processed (including showing of the Interstitial) at the time you rotate. Which means that it will be rescheduled after rotation, causing the Interstitial to be displayed again.

Solutions:

1. Show the interstitial directly from your first Activity. Ie don't have an Activity to specifically show the interstitial.
2. Review your code of your 2nd Activity and work out why it is causing the interstitial to redisplay.